# rust postgresql sql_query syntax error at end of input

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

When using diesel with my rust code, every time I use the sql_query with bind arguments, which means we use question mark for argument placement I got this error, "syntax error at end of input", no matter I use client_name (varchar) or id (int) for filtering.

```rust
        let a = sql_query("SELECT * FROM client WHERE client_name= ?").bind::<Varchar, _>("a");
        println!("query: {}", diesel::debug_query::<diesel::pg::Pg, _>(&a).to_string());
        let b = a.get_results::<Client>(&connection);
        println!("{:?}", b);
```

gives:

query: SELECT * FROM client WHERE client_name= ? -- binds: ["a"]
Err(DatabaseError(__Unknown, "syntax error at end of input"))

Comment: Placeholders in raw pgsql are of the form `$1` etc rather than `?`.

Comment: Your question is missing important information. Please include information about the used rust and diesel version, the used database backend and a minimal reproducible example in your question.

Answer (score 1):

As #eggyal pointed out, in pg we should always use $n as a placeholder.